# Laravel background color

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I am trying to give my view page a background color but it keeps on only giving me 3/4 of the page light blue when I want everything. (see screenshot) Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot

[image]

Here is the css code that I am using:
background.css

```
.container{
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

view.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<link href="{{ asset('css/background.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    You are logged in!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
<h1>Overview</h1>
<table class="table table-bordered"> 
 <tr> 
 <th><strong><big>Name: </big></strong></th> 

 <th><strong><big>Action: </big></strong></th>
 </tr> 
 <td> 
 <tr> 
 @foreach($data as $value) 
 <tr> 
 <th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->pi_id])}}">{{$value->Name}}</a></th> 

 <th><form action="{{ url('/home/'.$value->pi_id.'/delete') }}" method="get"> 
 {{ csrf_field() }} 
 <button type="submit">Delete</button> 
 </form></th> 
 </tr> 
 @endforeach
 </div> 

@endsection
```

Comment: where is a screenshot?

Comment: Just added, forgot to put in @Minai Chauhan

Comment: Please put the full HTML code (parsed one).

Comment: @SauravRastogi but this is my full code..

Comment: @blastme Where is the header & footer?

Comment: @SauravRastogi that is in another page, is that needed? If yes I will post it

Comment: @blastme Right click on the page and inspect elements, go through each div and see associated CSS.

Comment: @blastme Do you need the full height of the page to blue or the width?

Comment: @SauravRastogi I want the whole page to be blue but for some reason it only stay until half way

Comment: So give the color to `body`, not to the container selector only.

Comment: Oh my god it worked thanks a lot, maybe you can put your answer below so that I can upvote you @shukshin.ivan

Comment: Instead of giving a background color to .container try to give this color to his parent element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page is not blue since you assign the color to a container on page. Change your `css` style to

```
body{
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

You should also keep in mind, that total page layout is `layouts/app.blade.php`, you can find parent container `body` in it.